# Tikz Drawing Block

Tags: tikz-pgf, block

[image]

Hello everyone. How to draw this block in LaTeX using TikZ? Thank you for all.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Consider accepting one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 4):

[image: simple graph with arrows]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>={Latex[open,scale=1.2]}]

        \node[minimum width=5cm, minimum height=3cm,align=center,draw](B){Mathematical model\\of\\aircraft dynamics};
        \def\d{1.5} % distance for arrows
        \draw[<-] (B.155) --++ (-\d,0) node[left] (M) {$\eta$};
        \draw[<-] (B.170) --++ (-\d,0) node[left] {$\varepsilon$};
        \draw[<-] (B.190) --++ (-\d,0) node[left] {$\xi$};
        \draw[<-] (B.205) --++ (-\d,0) node[left] {$\zeta$};
        \node[above of=M] {Input variables};        
        
        \draw[->] (B.25) --++ (\d,0) node[right] (U) {$u$};
        \draw[->] (B.17) --++ (\d,0) node[right] {$w$};
        \draw[->] (B.9) --++ (\d,0) node[right] {$q,\theta$};
        \draw[->] (B.-9) --++ (\d,0) node[right] {$v$};
        \draw[->] (B.-17) --++ (\d,0) node[right] {$p,\phi$};
        \draw[->] (B.-25) --++ (\d,0) node[right] {$r,\psi$};
        \node[above of=U] {Output variables};
        
        \draw[dashed] (B.west) --++ (-4,0) coordinate (W);
        \node[above of=W] {Longitudinal};
        \node[below of=W] {Lateral-Directional};
        
        \draw[dashed] (B.east) --++ (3,0);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much:)))

Comment: I encourage you to learn from this straightforward code, then try and change some parameters, just for fun. Don't hesitate to vote and accept, in order to let know that you received a correct answer.

Comment: I think the `positioning`  tikzlibrary can be used by changing the syntax    `\node[above of=M] {Input variables};`  to `\node[above= of M] {Input variables};`

Comment: You're right, especially if one wants to position the words more precisely.

Answer (score 2):

I draw the left side of your graph as a starting point.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            
            % draw rectangle
            
            \node[minimum size=4cm,draw] (r) at  (0,0) {\makecell[c]{Mathematical Model \\ of \\ aircraft dynamics}};
            
            % draw arrows/lines
            
            \foreach \y/\lab [count=\i from 1] in {1.5/$\eta$, 0.75/$\epsilon$, -0.75/$\xi$, -1.5/$\zeta$} {
                \draw [-stealth] ($ (r.west) + (-1,\y)$) node[left] (a-\i) {\lab} -- ($ (r.west)  + (0,\y)$);
            }
            
            \draw [densely dashed] ($ (r.west) + (-3,0)$) node (l-1) {} -- (r.west);
            
            % labels
            
            \node[above=0.5cm] at (a-1.north) {Input variables};
            \node (lab-1) at (l-1 |- {$(a-3)!0.5!(a-4)$}) {Lateral-Directional};
            \node[anchor=west] (lab-2) at (lab-1.west |- {$(a-2)!0.5!(a-1)$}) {Logitudinal};
            
            
        \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

I saved the rectange as `r`, so you can copy parts of the left side and use it for the right side. Here, `r.east` would be interesting.

If there are questions, don't hesitate to ask them.

Comment: Thank you very much:)